# select row based on grouping value

Tags: sql

In the table Products in the link below, I have 3 columns. SupplierID, CategryID and Price. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_drop_table

I have the below query and I want to get only groupid is not null and do the "order by group id"
But adding these command in the query doesn't work.

```
select p.*,
       (case when SupplierID < 5  AND CategoriID < 10  then 1
             when 5 <= SupplierID and SupplierID < 10 AND CategoriID < 10 then 2
             else 3
        end) as groupid
from products p;
```

Can you please help me?

Thank you,
HHC

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
Select p.*,

       (Case When SupplierID < 5 AND CategoriID < 10  Then 1

             When 5 <= SupplierID and SupplierID < 10 AND CategoriID < 10 Then 2

             else 3

        end) as groupid

From products p 
Where groupid IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY groupid;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you rows that match the first two criteria.

```
where CategoriID < 10 and SupplierID < 10
```